# Tough question about infinite set on the plane

Tags: combinatorics

Here's a question I think is hard.

Consider a square S of side a in the plane. How many, at most, points P,Q of the square  can be chosen either within S or on the sides of S, such that their distance $|P-Q|\geq \sqrt{a}$?

This question troubles me because I can't grasp what I am to prove. If this was a Computer Science question, I would do a simulation for some values of a and a large number of random points to get the answer as a probability. 
But this is a Combinatorics question, and I do not get what does "how many" imply.

I mean, if it means cardinality, then we have this set obviously has the power of the continuum (as the plane has this property). Then how can it be compared to S?

If the answer involves area, then the condition $|P-Q|\geq a$ constructs a subregion of S, but this will be hard to describe algebraically...

Comment: Without the restriction possible answers depending on the distance are $\{0, 4,\dots, \infty\}$. Maybe this is what is asked?

Comment: How is this obtained? Tell me please...

Comment: I suspect the question was meant to be, "What is the maximum number $k$ such that points $p_1,p_2,\ldots, p_k$ can be chosen so that each $p_i$ lies inside $S$ or on its boundary, and the distance $|p_i - p_j|\ge\sqrt{a}$ for all $i\neq j$?

Comment: In general, this is not a solved problem.  See for example http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/csq/d1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hint:

This has nothing to do with infinity but with discrete geometry, or more precisely: with circle packings in the plane. The densest circle packing is the hexagonal packing. It gives you an upper bound, but you have to take care of boundary effects.

Comment: Circle packings? Next to nothing... Where can I find out more? Or maybe see how it applies here?  Edit: So we pack circles inside the square or the other way round? This is confusing...

Comment: @MelaniesWoes Packing circles inside the square. See my comment to your question. Choosing the points so that their distances are at least a given number $d$ is equivalent to packing discs of radius $d/2$ inside a square of side length $a+d$ (consider the centers of the discs).